# How to use the result of a completionHandler for the destination of a NavigationLink in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, completionhandler

I have a function which calls a REST API and returns the result via a completionHandler.

I want to call this function when pressing a NavigationLink but use the result as the object passed into the destination. Can't quite figure out how to do this, or if it's even possible. Here's my current code:

The REST function

```
   func postProgramme(programmeName: String, programmeDays: Int, programmeDescription: String, completeionHandler: @escaping ProgrammeCompletionHandler) {
        struct PostRoutineData: Codable {
            let programmeName: String
            let programmeDays: Int
            let programmeDescription: String
        }
        
        let postProgrammeData = PostRoutineData(programmeName: programmeName, programmeDays: programmeDays, programmeDescription: programmeDescription)
        
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(postProgrammeData)
            let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
            let request = RESTRequest(path: "/workout/programme", body: jsonString.data(using: .utf8))
            Amplify.API.post(request: request) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let data):
                    do {
                        //let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                        let programme = try self.decoder.decode(Programme.self, from: data)
                        completeionHandler(programme)
                    } catch {
                        print("[ERROR] Error within postProgrammes()", error)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("[ERROR] Error within postProgrammes()", error)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("[ERROR] Error within postProgramme()", error)
        }
    }
```

The NavigationLink, and my attempt to figure the problem out:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ProgrammeDetailView(), isActive: $shouldTransit) {
    Text("Create Programme")
         .onTapGesture {
              self.createNewProgramme()
              self.shouldTransit = true
    }
}
```

```
func createNewProgramme() -> ProgrammeDetailView {
        sessionManager.postProgramme(programmeName: programmeName, programmeDays: programmeDays, programmeDescription: programmeDescription, completeionHandler: {(programme) -> ProgrammeDetailView in
            return ProgrammeDetailView(programme: programme)}
    }
```

Comment: "want to call this function when pressing a NavigationLink but use the result as the object passed into the destination" Suppose the network interaction takes ten minutes. What's your plan? The interface remains unresponsive to the tap for ten minutes? Really? Might it not be better to want something a bit more sensible?

Comment: I don´t think this is a good design principle. Why not just letting the `ProgrammeDetailView` make the Api call on its `.onApear` and handle showing progress and errors. This would allow the user to go back if it takes too long or an network error occurs.

Comment: Thanks @matt I will redesign the logic as I didn't think of the point you raised matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's an iOS app, if you can deploy for iOS 15, you can use the recent async/ await environment, by using an async function and returning a `Programme`, instead of using a completion handler.

1. Turn your function into async and return a `Programme`:

```
   func postProgramme(programmeName: String, programmeDays: Int, programmeDescription: String) async -> Programme? {

        // ...
        
                case .success(let data):
                    do {
                        let programme = try self.decoder.decode(Programme.self, from: data)

                        // No completion handler: return a Programme
                        // completionHandler(programme)
                        return programme
                    } catch {
                        print("[ERROR] Error within postProgrammes()", error)

                        // Return nil everywhere else
                        return nil
                    }
```

2. In your main view, use a `@State` var of type `Programme?`, that will be binding to another variable in `ProgrammeDetailView`.

The function `createNewProgramme()` will update the state variable.

```
@State private var programme: Programme? = nil

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {

        // Pass the binding to ProgrammeDetailView
        NavigationLink(destination: ProgrammeDetailView(programme: $programme, content: { programme in
                  // A customised view
                  Text(programme?.name ?? "")
            }), isActive: $shouldTransit) {
            Text("Create Programme")
                 .onTapGesture {
                     self.createNewProgramme()
                     self.shouldTransit = true
                 }
        }
    }

func createNewProgramme() {

    // Task will allow working with async functions
    Task {
        let programme = await sessionManager.postProgramme(programmeName: programmeName, programmeDays: programmeDays, programmeDescription: programmeDescription)

        // Back to main thread to update the UI
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.programme = programme
        }
    }
}
```

3. Remember to create the `@Binding` variable in `ProgrammeDetailView`. The example below can receive any view as a parameter, but because the REST API will take some time to respond, you need to handle the case where `programme == nil`:

```
struct ProgrammeDetailView<V: View> : View {

    // The binding with the parent view
    @Binding var programme: Programme?

    // Your customised view that receives a Programme as a parameter
    let content: (Programme)->V

    var body: some View {
        if programme == nil {
             ProgressView()
        } else {
             content(programme!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you